# How do I limit a taxonomy dropdown exposed filter to the terms used by nodes in view results?

Tags: views, 8

I'm trying to create a custom node search view, that takes Taxonomy terms as a filter (dropdown - autocomplete not an option). The problem I have, is that there could be >1000 terms and I would like to restrict the dropdown to show only the taxonomy terms that are already in use by the nodes returned in the initial view results. Does this make sense?

Can anyone advise if this is possible, and if so, how best to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Like you can already read on the [bug report from Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/463678) which you've copied from, a good solution is to use [Views Selective Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_selective_filters). It does exactly you're asking for.

Comment: Now, Views selective filters module is avilable for drupal7 but i want to used this functionality in drupal8.

Comment: @rahulkumar.it you should've mentioned that from the beginning.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?